# how to know what is x when x maybe several type

Tags: javascript

how to know what is x in js?

sometimes I have to write an function with parameter which has several type. such as test(x); I need to know what is x before I run the code .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hello">hello</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // the x var will be random 1 of 4 bellow , how to know what is it ?
    var x = $('.hello')[0];
    var x = ['1','2'];
    var x = {'name':'jimmy'};
    var x = 'hello';

    if(???){
        // alert x is a html node
    }
    if(???){
        // alert x is a js arr
    }
    if(???){
        // alert x is a js obj
    }
    if(???){
        // alert x is a js str
}

</script>
```

Comment: **typeof** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: use type of... if(typeof(x) ) == 'S.T') do stuff

Comment: @Popnoodles unfortunately, that only goes part of the way. For example, `x`'s 1, 2 and 4 are all typeof `"object"`

Comment: `instanceof jQuery`. You can work the rest out surely?

Comment: @kiyarash typeof is an operator, not a function, so you don't need the parentheses to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(typeof x === 'string'){
    // string
} else {
    if(x instanceof Array){
        // array
    } else if(x.nodeType){
        // element
    } else if(typeof x === 'object') {
        // object
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqk9g/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This would work **in this case**:

```
var x = $('.hello')[0];
var x = ['1','2'];
var x = {'name':'jimmy'};
var x = 'hello';

if(x === undefined){
    // alert x is undefined
}else if(x === null){
    // alert x is null
}else if('nodeType' in x){
    // alert x is a html node
}else if(x instanceof Array){
    // alert x is a js arr
}else if(typeof x == 'string'){
    // alert x is a js str
}else if(x.constructor == Object){
    // alert x is a js obj
}
```

The most used way, is to detect types by unique properties each object has (`if(x.push)`), because js is a 'duck type' language. But for this case the above code works fine.

Hope this helps. Cheers